# Utility to create HTTP requests and analyze responses, with history (like Postman)

Tags: http

I'm looking for an alternative to [Postman](http://www.getpostman.com/) which is a Chrome extension but for Opera browser **or** as a standalone application.

I've tried [SoapUI](http://www.soapui.org), but it seemed really complex.

My basic needs are:

- Create HTTP requests
- Analyzing responses
- Have something like history since I'll be executing requests similar to each other

And some images on how Postman covers my needs:

[image: Analyzing responses]

[image: Create HTTP requests]

[image: History]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) might be worth a try.  It's pretty powerful and is more geared towards web development than tools like SoapUI, so it may suit your needs a bit better.

Comment: Fiddler looks good so far(+1), can you provide more details because from visiting their website I saw and standalone and a browser-extension version.Another thing is can you share(find) some screenshots or more details about how Fiddler covers the functionalities mentioned?

Comment: I'm not really in a position to provide examples or screenshots, I'm afraid.  I've always used the standalone version and found it pretty intuitive so my advice would be to just dive in and ask Google if you get stuck!

Comment: Ok Fiddler replaced Postman, I'm using the standalone version too, although UI seems a little ugly but it does what is supposed to do well enough, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[Runscope](https://www.runscope.com) covers all of your three requirements, and then some, especially in the history department. All of the requests you make using Runscope are stored, full request/response with URI, headers, etc. They're also indexed and tagged, so you can free text search the payload, by host, by status/error code, etc.

In response analysis, you can also place two requests side-by-side and compare them *diff* style. See a demo [screencast here](http://blog.runscope.com/posts/comparing-http-requests-using-runscope).

What's more, you take any request from the log, and convert it into a Runscope Radar automated test that runs from the cloud, complete with assertions (i.e. validate response code, content in the payload, etc.)

Note: I work for Runscope. That being said, I'm also a developer that has used Postman and SoapUI extensively. Both swell tools in their own right.

Answer (score 0):

I have written [FRequest](https://fabiobento512.github.io/FRequest/), works on both windows and mac. It is a standalone opensource desktop application and can run even as a portable one. It supports running http request and analyze the responses. Doesn't have a history concept but does allow you to save how much requests as you want in a project file (much like an IDE).

Check if it fits your needs, where's a screenshot:

[image]